# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\log (n^2+1)}{\log(n^2-1)}\right)^{n^2\log n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I've got

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\log (n^2+1)}{\log(n^2-1)}\right)^{n^2\log n}$$

So I've written

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n^2\log(n)·\log}\frac{\log (n^2+1)}{\log(n^2-1)}$$

But there I don't know how to simplify anything so I can't follow. Any hint?

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\frac{log (n^2+1)}{log(n^2-1)}\right)^{n^2log\:n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$\ln\Bigl(\frac{\ln(n^2+1)}{\ln(n^2-1)}\Bigr)=$$

$$\ln(1+\frac{ \ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})-\ln(1-\frac{1}{n^2})  }{\ln(n^2-1)})$$
$$\sim \frac{2}{n^2\ln(n^2-1)}$$

You should find $e$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* : $n^{2}\log n \log \dfrac{\log{n^{2}(1+1/n^2)}}{\log n^2(1-1/n^2)} = n^2\log n \log \dfrac{2\log n + 1/n^{2} + o(1/n^2)}{2\log n - 1/n^2} = n^{2} \log n \log (1 + \dfrac{1}{2n^2\log n }+o(1/\dots)) $

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

As an alternative by $n^2=e^x\to \infty $

$$\left(\frac{\log (e^x+1)}{\log(e^x-1)}\right)^{e^x\log e^{x/2}}=\left(\frac{\log e^x+\log (1+1/e^x)}{\log e^x+\log(1-1/e^x)}\right)^{\frac x 2e^x}=$$
$$=\left(\frac{x+\frac1{e^x}+o\left(\frac1{e^x}\right)}{x-\frac1{e^x}+o\left(\frac1{e^x}\right)}\right)^{\frac x 2e^x}=
\frac{\left(1+\frac1{xe^x}+o\left(\frac1{xe^x}\right)\right)^{\frac x 2e^x}}{\left(1-\frac1{xe^x}+o\left(\frac1{xe^x}\right)\right)^{\frac x 2e^x}}$$

then use that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(e^x)=L \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} f(n^2)=L$$